# What's the meaning of `packed feature`?

Tags: meaning

When I read the document of [PRTG features](https://www.paessler.com).

> PRTG comes packed with specialized monitoring features you’ll love learning to use.

What's the meaning of `packed feature` ?

Comment: It isn't _packed feature_, its a device which _is packed with features_, i.e. full of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means it has a lot of features. Same as a pillow is packed with feathers.